# URL monitor issue - Dynatrace 6.1

Tags: dynatrace

I have created a URL monitor to check the availability of website.I kept all values as it is in monitor tab and added host( http://abcd.xyz.org ). I scheduled it for every 10 minutes in schedule tab. In Measure tab I put the Lower sever value of HostReachable measure to 0.
I created incident , added HostReachable measure and put its Aggregation to last value. Evaluation time frame is 1 minutes.In Action tab I put my email for notification.

Now after every 10 minutes I started getting email even I browsed the website and it's working fine. Couldn't understand if website loading fine then why incidents occurs.

Email message:
Violations
HostReachable: STG URL Monitor@abcd.xyz.org: Was 0.00 but should be higher than 0.00.

Latest logs given below:
2016-08-17 15:42:33 INFO [UrlMonitor@STG URL Monitor_0] Previous message was repeated 1 times.
2016-08-17 15:42:33 INFO [UrlMonitor@STG URL Monitor_0] Executing method: GET, URI: http://abcd.xyz.org:80/

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could have to do with the evaluation timeframe of your Incident. If your monitor is scheduled to run every 10 minutes but your evaluation timeframe is 1 minute it means that you have 9 evaluations where there is "no data".
We typically recommend to align the monitor execution with the Incident. Can you give that a try?
Also - I typically chart these measures to see which values the monitor produces in which timeinterval. this is an easy visual verification check to make sure that e.g: the monitor works correctly and delivers data. Can you do that?

I also wanted to say that we have a very good Dynatrace Online Community and Discussion forum @ http://answers.dynatrace.com. You might want to try to post future questions there as there are 100k+ Dynatrace users active on that community

Andi

Comment: I changed the evaluation time-frame to 10 minutes so now I am not getting any email in every 10 minutes. Hope now incidents will work as expected and will get if really server gets down.
Actually I post question on dynatrace forum but couldn't get any response then I post on SO.

Anyway Thanks for your reply on this...your response worked out for me

Comment: Actually we have hosted website on two hosting server(Host1 and Host2) in clustered environment so as of now I created two URL monitor and accordingly two incidents to check availability. In Hosts section I added Host1 for URL monitor 1 and Host2 for URL monitor 2. Can I create only one URL monitor to check website availability and add website URL www.mywebsitename.com in Hosts section. Would this work?

Comment: great to hear it worked - sorry that you didnt get a reply on our forum so far. as for your second question. I suggest you create a hostgroup called "websites" and add your two sites to that hostgroup. then simply use this group for just one monitor. the monitor will then be executed against every host in the group. I think I covered exactly that scenario in this perf clinic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ysh_HL8HDoA&list=PLqt2rd0eew1bmDn54E2_M2uvbhm_WxY_6&index=11